# In GRASS GIS db.execute IN statement works, but NOT IN doesn't

Tags: grass-gis, database

Here is my command:

```
db.execute sql="UPDATE table SET factor=number2 WHERE label IS NOT NULL AND number2 IN (SELECT label FROM table)"
```

This command sets TRUE on those rows, where label in not NULL and corresponding number2 is contained in all label values from the table. It works well.

But.. It's not exactly what I want.
I want where number2 NOT IN (SELECT...). But it doesn't work.
It doesn't give any error, simply "factor" column is empty after running the command.

UPD:
`UPDATE table SET factor=number2 WHERE number IS NOT NULL AND number2 NOT IN (SELECT label FROM table WHERE number IS NOT NULL)` this works after correcting data types.

UPD2:
Markus, I don't think I am able to edit your link, or I am simply not aware, howto.
It is something like

```
db.execute sql="UPDATE table SET column1=column2 WHERE column2 NOT IN     (SELECT column3 FROM table)" wont work if there are some NULL values in column3.
```

You should exclude NULLs like this:

```
db.execute sql="UPDATE table SET column1=column2 WHERE column2 NOT IN (SELECT column3 FROM table WHERE column3 IS NOT NULL)"
```

Comment: We would need to know: which GRASS GIS version and which database backend do you use (there are different SQL dialects...)?

Comment: SQL Lite 3.27, grass 7.8.7

Comment: If you think this might become an example on https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/grass-sqlite.html then please suggest it (edit link at page bottom).

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten about my other question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/330900/in-grass-gis-db-execute-in-statement-works-but-not-in-doesnt/330915#330915

Comment: So, I think it could be an example yes.

Comment: Markus, I don't think I am able to edit your link, or I am simply not aware, howto.
It is something like 

```
db.execute sql="UPDATE table SET column1=column2 WHERE column2 NOT IN (SELECT column3 FROM table)" wont work if there are some NULL values in column3. You should exclude NULLs like this:
db.execute sql="UPDATE table SET column1=column2 WHERE column2 NOT IN (SELECT column3 FROM table WHERE column3 IS NOT NULL)"
```

Comment: Oh, a manual creation glitch as it lacks the section which refers to the page source code (I'll fix it). Please edit here:  https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/main/db/drivers/sqlite/grass-sqlite.html